# What happened to Doorknob?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Before anyone asks this question I'd like to get it out of the way:

---

If I go to the [moderators tab](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), I don't see [Doorknob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3808/doorknob) any more:

[image: Moderators screenshot with doorknob missing]

He used to be a moderator here, but now he's not.  What happened?

Answer (score 44):

Doorknob's moderator privileges were removed today, due to inactivity.  We have not been able to contact Doorknob for quite some time.  He either cannot be reached or does not want to be reached.  Naturally, we respect his wishes either way, and we expect community to do the same.

We thank him for his time here as the longest standing moderator of CGCC and all he has done for us, and we would welcome him back to the community if he returned. (Stack Exchange moderators are elected for life and so can apply for reinstatement at any time.) Regardless, we wish him the best!

Please note that this will not result in any major changes in moderation activity—it is effectively just a housekeeping change. We prefer that only active accounts have moderator privileges in order to reduce the possibility of security breaches.

Comment: I was for a long time off this site and was attracted back due the upcoming elections. I stopped participating here due to a strong grudge and disagreement on Doorknob and his moderation style and the SE's 2019 Monica fiasco just made it worse. Since now he is gone for some time, I think that maybe it is time to come back to the old days of fun in this site. Anyway, I hope for us both we should be much better people now than what we were 8 years ago and if he ever comes back, I will hope that the problems for those old days stays in the old days.